# R evcent values are positive for degree 0?

Tags: r, igraph

I'm using evcent to determine EC's for my vertices. I notice that there can be resulting positive values for vertices that have degree=0. This should not be able to happen! Is it a numerical problem?

I used:

```
ecs <- evcent(g)$vector
```

Also, to see if it's numerical problem I tried to include a named list to increase the number of iterations in the ARPACK algorithm:

```
namedList<-list()
namedList["iter"]<-100

ecs <- evcent(g, options=namedList)$vector
```

That didn't change the number of iterations. So can you answer if this is a numerical problem or my understanding of the theory is wrong and if it is a numerical problem how to change the number of iterations. I suppose I could correct it based on the degree.

Here is a reproducible example:

```
> V(temppg)
Vertex sequence:
 [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11
> E(temppg)

Edge sequence:

[1]   3 --  2
[2]   4 --  2
[3]   5 --  2
[4]   6 --  2
[5]   7 --  2
[6]   8 --  2
[7]   9 --  2
[8]  10 --  2
[9]   4 --  3
[10]  5 --  3
[11]  7 --  3
[12]  8 --  3
[13]  9 --  3
[14] 10 --  3
[15]  5 --  4
[16]  6 --  4
[17]  7 --  4
[18]  8 --  4
[19]  9 --  4
[20] 10 --  4
[21] 11 --  4
[22]  7 --  5
[23]  8 --  5
[24]  9 --  5
[25] 10 --  5
[26] 11 --  5
[27]  9 --  6
[28] 10 --  6
[29] 11 --  6
[30]  8 --  7
[31]  9 --  7
[32] 10 --  7
[33]  9 --  8
[34] 10 --  9
[35] 11 --  9


tempec <- evcent(temppg)$vector

> tempec
 [1] 0.0256601 1.0000000 0.7269698 0.6933415 0.5969578 0.8510570 0.8601283 0.8512843
 [9] 0.9912620 0.9523037 0.6248307
```

So why, if vertex has degree=0 does it get an eigenvector centrality of 0.0256601?

Comment: Please add a reproducible example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eigenvector centrality is ill-defined for disconnected networks.

The basic idea of the eigenvector centrality is that the centrality score of each vertex should be proportional to the sum of the centrality scores of its neighbors. It follows easily that the eigenvector centrality scores of nodes that are in different components of the same network cannot influence each other in any way (since there is no path between them). If you don't see this immediately, just try to multiply the eigenvector centrality score of every vertex within the same connected component with the same nonzero constant *c* - the equations of eigenvector centrality will still hold for every vertex! So, the usual way to calculate eigenvector centrality scores is to calculate it for the different connected components of the graph independently.

In your case, the vertex with degree zero is a connected component on its own. What shall its centrality score be? On one hand, one could say that its eigenvector centrality score is zero since it has no neighbors at all. On the other hand, one could argue that its eigenvector centrality could be 1 or any other non-negative number since this vertex is the *most central* (and of course the only) vertex within its own component (and we know that the eigenvector centrality scores in different components are not comparable to each other).

igraph does not care about all this - it simply finds an eigenvector of the adjacency matrix and returns that, since we know from the definition of eigenvector centrality that it is an eigenvector of the adjacency matrix. The vector that you see *is* an eigenvector. The only problem is that due to the disconnectedness of your network, its adjacency matrix has infinitely many eigenvectors, and some of these may not coincide with your intuition about the centrality of some vertices (since your intuition says that vertices with zero degree should have zero centrality).